# in-cell newlines (in tabular environments)?

Tags: tables, line-breaking

I'm working on a table containing multi-line cells and I wonder if the following concept is supported by LaTeX.

The concept itself is simple: allow a cell to span multiple lines by increasing the line height (similar to how it works in Office suites when you press Ctrl-Enter or Alt-Enter to wrap the current cell). Using `\\` doesn't work as it causes LaTeX to go to the next table row.

Thus what would be required is an equivalent of `\\` which is scoped to a table cell. Is this implemented already (I suppose not in LaTeX, but perhaps there are packages)?

I realize that the same can be achieved with \multirow, but I don't find that approach very user-friendly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sure, just use `\newline` instead of `\\`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{5cm}|p{5cm}|}
\hline
foo & foo \\
\hline
line\newline break & another \newline break \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Only works if you use p and specify the size of the (of all?!) column(s)

Comment: Or `\linebreak` which has the advantage to give the correct alignment when `\centering` or `\raggedleft` is used in the column.