# \newline not working with booktabs?

Tags: tables, line-breaking

A while ago I had a question about having multi-line strings in a table cell (
[in-cell newlines (in tabular environments)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3748/in-cell-newlines-in-tabular-environments)).

I remember seeing it working but I've just tried to use it again and ... `\newline` did nothing.

A test LaTeX source is below, which, despite the `\newline` commands, it did not split the cells on multiple lines:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}
\RequirePackage[l2tabu,orthodox]{nag}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.6}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[final,babel]{microtype}
\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}
\setlist{nolistsep}
\frenchspacing

\begin{table}[htp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l l l l@{}}
          \toprule
           & \textbf{Foo} & {\textbf{Bar}} & \textbf{Baz} \\
          \midrule
            \textbf{Single line} & foo1 foo2 & bar1 bar2 & baz1 baz2 \\
            \textbf{Multiline} & foo1 \newline foo2 & bar1 \newline bar2 & baz1 \newline baz2 \\
          \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption {\small{bla bla}}\label{my-label}
\vspace*{-3mm}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Far from *minimal* example, and nothing to do with booktabs.

Comment: I put the packages that I thought might influence it (and thought booktabs was used since it's imported). Sorry about \vspace, I missed it when editing the real table.

Comment: You should have *tried* which of the packages influence it before posting the question...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use tabular p specifier instead of l.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l p{2cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}@{}}
    & \textbf{Foo} & {\textbf{Bar}} & \textbf{Baz} \\
    \textbf{Single line} & foo1 foo2 & bar1 bar2 & baz1 baz2 \\
    \textbf{Multiline} & foo1 \newline foo2 & bar1 \newline bar2 & baz1 \newline baz2 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: it doesn't work. I had tried it before posting, I got "Missing number, treated as zero" on the line declaring the table header.My tabular declaration was \begin{tabular}{@{}p p p p@{}}

Comment: The format is p{length}. Minimal example attached.