# Specify line break in booktabs tabular without specifying cell width

Tags: tables, line-breaking, multirow

I have a table with lots of columns which will most of the available horizontal space in my page layout.
And I would like to add a "note" of sorts to the bottom of the table, which:

- Spans the width of the whole table but does not influence its width
- Contains wrapped text, either by wrapping automatically (preferred) or with manually specified line breaks

This is as far as I've been able to reduce the problem so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
    {} & {(baseline)} & {case 1} & {case 2} & {case 3}{$^\ast$} \\
    \hline
    var 1 & 327 & 621 & 0.315 & 1189       \\
    var 2 & 1604 & 1395 & -0.224 & 1395     \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize$^\ast$some explanation on what this means which did \newline not fit into the cell, or in the table width}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This yields the following:

[image: table with 5 columns and some text across the bottom. The last column is stretched to accommodate the text, and a space is missing where the code specified the \newline command]

As you can see, `\newline` is happily ignored (note the missing space), and the last column is stretched to accommodate the text.

I've seen [a suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4248/newline-not-working-with-booktabs) to change the alignment to `p{<some_width>}`. If I do, it will indeed obey the `\newline`, but it will *also* impose whatever width I enter on the text, which either stretches the table or wraps it prematurely unless I guess "correctly".

I can of course iteratively adjust the width I'm specifying for the last column, but that is tedious, and I'm *almost* certain that there is a better way of achieving the following picture, than by changing the width parameter, millimeter by millimeter, to the largest value at which it does not affect the table width:

[image: The text at the bottom now wraps where it should, at whatever width the table would have if the text was not present]

**=> How can I do this?**

In case this is relevant: My full-size table also uses `siunitx` and `booktabs` for formatting, and maybe those offer some help. I removed them here to minimize the MWE.

I did try adding `\multirow` to the cell at the bottom, but that will only increase the height of the cell at the bottom and center the same single line of text vertically.

I'd be content to just have something which allows me to use `\newline` without specifying cell width, although of course automatic line wraps to "whatever width the tabular already has" would be preferred.

Also of interest: Why on earth is `\newline` only respected if cell width is *also* explicitly given? That makes precious little sense to me... I thought that the main use case for it was to specify a line break *in order* to allow narrower columns, and then let cell width adapt to the new line lengths. Or maybe it conflicts with `multirow`?

#### Edit: More things that don't really do it for me:

I could put two cells below the table and put part of the text in each of them, but then the line spacing would be messed up (One of these has wrapped text in a single cell, the other one has two cells, can you tell which is which?):
[image: Two almost identical tables side by side. The left one has two cells for the "footnote" with one line of text in each, and the other has one cell with a wrapped note in it. The one on the left has very awkwardly large line spacing for the note.]

Comment: You mention "booktabs" in the title of your query, but your code does not load the `booktabs` package nor does it employ any of the user macros of that package. Please clarify.

Comment: @Mico I have a much larger document which uses `booktabs`. In order to get a smaller example code, I removed that here, and replaced the `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` commands with `\hline`. The original table is also a good deal more complex, but I've been told not to post big complicated things here if a simple example with fewer package requirements demonstrates the issue just as well. -- but if you have an idea how to solve it using `booktabs`, I'd be delighted since I already use it anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you look into what the [threeparttable](https://ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable) package, its user environments (called `threeparttable` and `tablenotes`), and its user macro `\tnote` can do for you. Importantly, the width of the `tablenotes` environment is set to that of the associated `tabular` environment -- no need for any `\newline` directives.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\newcolumntype{T}{S[table-format=4.0]} % for 3 of the 4 data columns
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{threeparttable}
    
    \begin{tabular}{@{} l T T S[table-format=-1.3] T }
    \toprule
    & {(baseline)} & {case 1\tnote{$\dagger$}} & {case 2} & {case 3\tnote{*}} \\
    \midrule
    var 1 & 327 & 621 & 0.315 & 1189       \\
    var 2 & 1604 & 1395 & -0.224 & 1395     \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}

    \smallskip
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tablenotes}
    \item[$\dagger$] Some explanation of what this means which did not fit into the cell, but it fits below the table.
    \item[*]Some explanation of what this means which did not fit into the cell, but it fits below the table.
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: The OP has asked me to provide the following two points.

- A `threeparttable` environment contains up to 3 formal elements: (a) A `tabular`-like environment; (b) a `\caption` directive; and (c) a `tablenotes` environment. The `threeparttable` machinery limits the widths of the caption and of the tablenotes material to that of the `tabular`-like environment.
- To use a `threeparttable` environment inside a `table` environment, one should modify the code shown above as follows:  One should change

  ```
  \begin{center}
      \begin{threeparttable}

      \begin{tabular}{...}
      ...
      \end{tabular}

      \smallskip\footnotesize
      \begin{tablenotes}
      ...
      \end{tablenotes}
      \end{threeparttable}
  \end{center}
  ```

  to

  ```
  \begin{table}
  \centering % note: '\centering', not '\begin{center}'
      \begin{threeparttable}

      \caption{...} % <-- new

      \begin{tabular}{...}
      ...
      \end{tabular}

      \smallskip\footnotesize
      \begin{tablenotes}
      ...
      \end{tablenotes}

      \end{threeparttable}

  \end{table}
  ```

Comment: That solves the MWE, but when I applied it to my big document, all the line spacings and cell heights were increased. I then pasted my table into the MWE code, and it looks fine. Then I pasted the MWE code into my big document, and line spacings are weird again. Simply switching the environment for *any* table to  `threeparttable` in my document increases cell height and line spacing ... any clue where I should start looking?

Comment: @Zak - "Simply switching the environment for *any* table to threeparttable ..." -- Please note that I did not advocated *switching* to a `threeparttable`. Instead, I suggest *encasing* the `tabular` material, plus the explanatory material, inside a `threeparttable` environment.

Comment: I had my `tabular` inside a `table` environment which also contained a label and a caption. I then changed from `table` to `threeparttable` -- is that now how it should be used?

Comment: @Zak - *Absolutely not*. The sample code you posted did *not* feature either a `table` environment or a `\caption` directive; that's why my answer didn't feature those items either. If your real code does feature a `table` environment and a `\caption` directive (along with an associated `\label` directive), then you should definitely keep these items. What I advocated was to encase the `tabular`-like environment (along with the `\caption` statement and a newly-created `tablenotes` environment) inside a `threeparttable` environment which, in turn, should be contained in the `table` environment.

Comment: @Zak - Put differently, the `threeparttable` environment is not a substitute for a `table` environment -- or, for that matter, a `tabular` environment.

Comment: thanks for the info. I did not include the `table` environment because I've seen quite a few instances here on stackexchange where people were told in very authoritative manner to minimize their MWEs properly -- so I removed anything that was not necessary to explain the problem.

Comment: @zak - you made a mistake in editing my code. The three formal parts of a `threeparttable` environment are a `\caption` directive, a `tabuIar`-like environment, and a `tablenotes` environment. Hence, the `\caption` directlive has to be *inside* the `threeparttable` environment. I will revert to the original code.

Comment: @Zak - Given that your real code employs a `table` environment, it's unfortunate that you chose to omit that aspect from your posting.

Comment: would you mind correcting the code instead? Otherwise, there is no definite information here about how `threeparttable` is supposed to work in a `table` environment. Leaving the caption outside also does not seem to cause any issues, since floats accept captions as well.

Comment: Actually, I just found that moving the caption inside the threeparttable sets the caption line width to be equal to the able width. The documentation is pretty short (and does not mention this), so there may be some more detail I'm unaware of, but there may well be cases where it is useful to put the caption outside the `threeparttable` environment, e.g. to allow the caption to be wider  than the table, in cases where the table is fairly narrow. I've tried it out, and it does not seem to break anything.

Comment: @Zak - I've posted an addendum to address the topics you've mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Since Mico did not like me adding more detail to his answer, I'll just post it here:

`threeparttable` is not a floating environment, and its "three parts" are table, notes and caption. So when using `table` floating environment, the `threeparttable` needs to be wrapped around just the `tabular`, the notes and (optionally, see below) the caption, like this:

```
\begin{table}   
    \centering
    %any other setup, e.g. `\sisetup` when using `siunitx`
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \begin{tabular}
            % ... the actual table, including `\tnote{}` tags
        \end{tabular}
        \footnotesize % optional, of course, otherwise notes have same text size as table content
        \begin{tablenotes}
            % explanations for the `\tnote{}` tags
        \end{tablenotes}
    \caption{the caption for the table}
    \end{threeparttable}
    \label{tab:tpt_example}
\end{table}
```

Although the [package documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable) states that the caption should be inside the `threeparttable`, I found that both inside or outside work, and both have use cases:

- Keeping it inside will cause the caption to have the same width as the table but otherwise work the same as normal `table` captions.
- Moving it behind or before the `threeparttable` environment causes its width to match the `table` floating environment instead. That may be useful in some cases, particularly with narrow tables, when the caption contains a bit more text and there is enough space left and right.

Comment: Regarding your second bullet point: If the `tabular` material is quite narrow and if it's desirable to let the width of the `\caption` material exceed that of the `tabular` material, this argument probably holds for the `tablenotes` material as well. And if it's desirable to keep both the caption and the tablenotes outside the `threeparttable` environment, there isn't a need to employ the `threeparttable` machinery to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

The package `nicematrix` provides an environment `{NiceTabular}` with its own command `\tabularnote` to address that kind of situation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{lcccc}
   \toprule
   & (baseline) & case 1 & case 2 & case 3\tabularnote{some explanation on what this means which did not fit into
     the cell, or in the table width} \\ 
   \midrule
   var 1 & 327 & 621 & 0.315 & 1189 \\
   var 2 & 1604 & 1395 & -0.224 & 1395 \\
   \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]